# Making varnish configuration GUI panel

Tags: caching, user-interface, web, panel, varnish

I want to make a GUI panel for my varnish configuration, so the user can simply changing the configuration value without coding the vcl file. Any advice ? I'm planning using php for the programming languange. Is it good idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [Varnish Administration Console](https://www.varnish-software.com/product/varnish-administration-console-0) (Pay alert!) or the [Varnish Agent 2](https://github.com/varnish/vagent2) which both have a dashboard with VCL editing functionalities.

Comment: thx for the info, very helpful. I interesting with varnish agent 2. Did you ever use it ? How to install it ? I'm using in my virtualbox.

Comment: Yes, i've used it several times now and the installation is very easy.  Have a look at https://github.com/varnish/vagent2/blob/master/INSTALL.rst.

Comment: okay thx arjan I didn't notice the install.rst. After I sucessfully install, the varnish agent still cannot communicating. I tried access the index html via browser and I'm get this error : _italic_Failed to fetch agent version
Not Found
error
[object Object] Any help ?

Comment: Are your sure the agent is running? Try http://hostname:6085/html/ for the HTML front-end. All arguments of varnish-agent are optional, but a password-file is required, see the -K option. The Varnish Agent will read other necessary options from the shm-log.

Comment: Yeah my varnish is running, I checked with typing varnishlog and running. I tried to access index.html with 192.168.XX.XXX:6085/my_varnish_agent/ folder but nothing happen. Is it I'm doing something wrong ? how to setup the password ?

Comment: I understand Varnish is running, but is varnish-agent also running? Varnish Agent is a separate application and you have to start it by your own. Really have a look at the documentation (https://github.com/varnish/vagent2); it answers all your questions.

Comment: how to test if the varnish agent is running ? I test the varnish agent with access the index html. I tried typing varnish-agent -k but I got error _italic_varnish agent: option requires an argument -- 'K' , varnish-agent: cannot open file /etc/varnish/agent_secret_italic_ I tried to search the agent_secret folder and I didn't find it. Any suggestion ?